# Modify proxied server response headers with nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I am coding a github client for fun and a little bit programming experience. GitHub API requires secret token which I don't want to store in my app or input every time. So I would like to bring up `nginx` proxy to `proxy_pass` requests to GitHub API and set authorization header with my secret token on them. I also need to modify response headers because GitHub provides pagination by means of `Link` header in responses and I have to replace api.github.com to my-proxy-server.com in the links.

While it is rather straightforward how to modify *request* headers it is unclear how to modify *response* ones. Is it possible at all? Or I have to build nginx with some additional modules?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60252545/remove-charset-in-content-type-header/60252738#60252738) is the example of modifying response header.

Comment: This is useful, thanks. But is it possible to perform global string substitution inside the variable(like `s/old/new/gi`) instead of replacing its full value?

Comment: Do you really need a global substitution or it will be suffient to substitute only one substring?

Comment: I have to substitute multiple ocurences of `api.github.com` in string like this `<https://api.github.com/user/25254/repos?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/25254/repos?page=10>; rel="last",...` As I understand, it can be done via multiple `map`s or things like `njs`/`lua` and there is no such thing as `s/old/new/g` in nginx?

Comment: No, nginx regex capabilities are quite limited, there is no such thing as global substitution (or any other regex flags, the only existed thing is case sensitive/insensitive match via `~`/`~*`). With multiply `map` blocks chain each `map` construction can replace only one occurence of substring, I'm also think LUA will be the best approach. Is there only one `Link` header you need to change or there can be multiply `Link` headers?

Comment: Only one, so I won't be affected by known issue with duplicate headers

Comment: I would use [`ngx.header.link`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxheaderheader) for this case. BTW if you ever need to work with multiply headers see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016867/how-come-i-cannot-set-multiple-cookies/44016904#44016904) solution.